# How to shift/rotate an array of items to a specific index in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery collection of elements (images).

```
var images = $('img');
```

I want to alter the collection so that it starts at a specific index, and the previous items are appended to the end. Sort of like a [Rolodex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolodex).

I could also convert them to an array if necessary. An example of this with a JavaScript array:

```
var images = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3'];
// rotate through to index 2
// images should == ['image2', 'image3', 'image0', 'image1']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Array, you could do this:

```
images.push.apply(images, images.splice(0, i));
```

```js
var images = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3'];
var i = 2;


images.push.apply(images, images.splice(0, i));


document.body.textContent = images.join(",");
```

There's a limit to how many items can be passed to `.apply()`, but it's in the thousands. If that's an issue, then you can push individual items from the `.splice()` in.

Comment: Well, colour me impressed, admittedly this was only my first thought on the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6tr33m78/ but: well done! :)

Comment: What is `push` and why is it here?

Comment: It will work just for static and sorted array we know. But what you will do if it will be dynamic, nonsorted array? I think its a bad way to resolve this problem.

Comment: @Andrew: It's a variadic function used to add items to an Array. By calling it via `Function.prototype.apply`, we can pass an Array of items to add to `images`, and they will be passed as the individual variadic parameters. The `.splice()` removes the items and returns them in an Array, so that's what's passed to `.apply()` and therefore to `.push()`.

Comment: @JerryCauser: Not sure what you mean. Sorting should be irrelevant for what the OP wants to do.

Comment: How to perform the same from any particular index?

Answer (score 3):

If it was an array, it's trivial with `Array.splice`:

```
> x = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3'];
[ 'image0',
  'image1',
  'image2',
  'image3' ]
> x = x.splice(2).concat(x)
[ 'image2',
  'image3',
  'image0',
  'image1' ]
> x = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3'];
[ 'image0',
  'image1',
  'image2',
  'image3' ]
> x = x.splice(3).concat(x)
[ 'image3',
  'image0',
  'image1',
  'image2' ]
>
```

Splice does in-place chopping out of stuff, what you're left with is the  spliced first two elements. We put that into X. The original array is modified in place, so it points to what it was at the original referencing time, so, the remaining n elements. So you concat to those remaining elements the spliced first two.

You can even use negative values and play with it, move forward and backward:

```
> x = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3'];
[ 'image0',
  'image1',
  'image2',
  'image3' ]
> x = x.splice(-1).concat(x)
[ 'image3',
  'image0',
  'image1',
  'image2' ]
> x = x.splice(1).concat(x)
[ 'image0',
  'image1',
  'image2',
  'image3' ]
> x = x.splice(-3).concat(x)
[ 'image1',
  'image2',
  'image3',
```

Comment: Very elegant, I like!

Answer (score 1):

If you need smart sort function, then you can put function into sort as argument with your algorithm. For your task it can be like that:

```js
var images = ['image5','image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3','image4'];
var magicNum = 2 -1;//your offset with shift = 1
images.sort(function(a,b){
  a = parseInt(a.substr(5))-magicNum,
  b = parseInt(b.substr(5))-magicNum;
  
  if(a*b<=0) return a>0?-1:b>0?1:0;
  else return a-b;
});

document.body.textContent = images.join(", ");
```

It can be used even on big nonsorted dynamic arrays. Also this method more scalable than method with splice and push.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7];

function rot(arr, ind)
{
    var narr = [];
 var len = arr.length;
 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
 {
     narr.push((i+ind<len?arr[i+ind]:arr[len-i-1]));
 }
    return narr;
}

rot(arr,2); // returns 4,5,6,7,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data_all= ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul" , 'Aug' ,'Sep' , 'Oct' , 'Nov' , 'Dec'];
data_all.push(data_all.shift());
```