# Shift last added element on first place, rest of them sort by name

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have `javascript array` that is populated with data from `backend API`. Also, new items can be added to `array`. Every item has `CreatedAt` key. I show data in table, and the first row should be exactly last added, rest of them should be ordered ascending. So I need some kind of custom sorting.

Here is example for initial, and final (desired) array:

```js
var initial = [
  {id: 1, name: "A", createdAt: "15/01/2018"},
  {id: 2, name: "B", createdAt: "20/01/2018"},
  {id: 3, name: "C", createdAt: "25/01/2018"},
  {id: 4, name: "D", createdAt: "10/02/2018"},
  {id: 5, name: "E", createdAt: "15/02/2018"},
];



var final = [
  {id: 5, name: "E", createdAt: "15/02/2018"},
  {id: 1, name: "A", createdAt: "15/01/2018"},
  {id: 2, name: "B", createdAt: "20/01/2018"},
  {id: 3, name: "C", createdAt: "25/01/2018"},
  {id: 4, name: "D", createdAt: "10/02/2018"}
];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shift/rotate an array of items to a specific index in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508902/how-to-shift-rotate-an-array-of-items-to-a-specific-index-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: This is literally two calls to [built-in array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Or if it can be done directly on stored procedure, in select statement, it would be better.

Comment: do you want sort by another key as well?

Comment: Yes, as I said, only the one with last CreatedAt value at the top, the rest of them sort by Name ascending. So I think it would be ok if I do it on sql procedure.